# loss of data on dataset

Tags: database, vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I was checking my database when I saw this problem.

I added 1 line of data on my database and when I run the program it didn't show up, so I removed the datagrid view from my form and configured the datasource with the wizard.

After I have configured my datasources with wizard (in this case my datasource is supDataSet), and dragged the datagridview and run the problem I realised that I loss the data that there was on the dataset. And I can see the data that I inserted into the database.

Can anyone help me with this? Is this normal ? And how to avoid this situations? And why the data that I inserted into the database didn't show ?

And if this is normal is there any way to transfer the data at the dataset to the database ?

Comment: Sounds like VB.NET **not** VB6.  If the db is added to the project, and  "Copy To Output Directory" is not Never, then each time you run, a new copy of the DB is used.  This is so you will have a blank DB to distribute when development is done.

Comment: @Plutonix
 But everytime I click on configure data source with wizard, all of the data that there was in the output is gone.

Comment: anyone that can help me ?